# Python global text area

Tags: python, layout, tkinter, global-variables

I have a text area created in initUI(self) function and would like to add to its contents in another one. When I initialize the text area as global on top of the class, the area is created in an another window, which is not what I want. I have seen questions related to the global variables but not something like this.

```
from Tkinter import*
textArea = Text() # creates another window
class test(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        mainFrame = Frame(self, parent)
        textArea  = Text(maınFrame, height=10, width=10)
        textArea.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        textArea.insert(INSERT, "abc")
    def changeText():
        global textArea
        textArea.insert(INSERT, "def")
```

thanks

Comment: You have two variables with the same name, one variable of instance and one global, it's a bad issue.

Comment: I am using global in the function as suggested in many answers. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them"

Comment: The example with the same variable names is only for explanation purpose. You should avoid doing so.

Answer (score 1):

`global` isn't necessary when you need a variable to be shared between two methods belonging to the same class. You can just attach the variable you need to `self`.

```
from Tkinter import*
class test(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        mainFrame = Frame(self, parent)
        self.textArea  = Text(maınFrame, height=10, width=10)
        self.textArea.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.textArea.insert(INSERT, "abc")
    def changeText(self):
        self.textArea.insert(INSERT, "def")
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, I don't have self as a parameter in changeText(). I wrote the code above to illustrate the problem. Do you know why I am having an error as "changeText takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)" when I put self in it and dont get any for other functions eventhough they have self as a parameter ?

Comment: All non-static class methods should have `self` as their first paramter. How are you calling `changeText`? Like `myTestFrameInstance.changeText()`, right?

Comment: its called when a button is pressed. button = Button(mainFrame, text="connect", command = changeText) in initUI()

Comment: I tried that and had the error "class instance has no attribute 'changeText' .. thats insteresting because I don't get any error for the other function that stops mainloop

Comment: Ok, I think I know why. Since I am using IDLE in Rpi as the compiler, I am not having indentation errors or anything else. the error I am having is probably due to spaces. Thanks for the help Kevin.